# ViewContent meta Pixel not passing product name parameter

Tags: module, magento2.4.5, pwa, venia, facebook-pixel

We are using PWA Venia Reactjs setup and We integrated **Meta pixel** event called **ViewContent** in our site using below code :

src/components/ProductFullDetail/ProductFullDetail.Js

```
<script>
fbq('track', 'ViewContent');
</script>
```

we want to pass "**Product name**" as parameter for event "**ViewContent**" . So we tried below code

```
fbq('track','ViewContent', {
    'name': product?.name
    });
```

Here is full code : https://pastebin.com/LLDEt8ig

**Issue** :

We can not able to fetch the **parameter** Product name in PDP Page.

We are getting only **event** ViewContent in PDP Page :

[image]

But We need **parameters** along with event **ViewContent** :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Baby in Magento

In the below file,
src/components/ProductFullDetail/ProductFullDetail.Js

Add this code hope this will work for you

```
const productMeta = () => {
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
        'content_name': product?.name,
        'content_ids': product.id,
        'content_type': 'product',
        'value': product?.price_range?.maximum_price?.final_price.value,
        'currency': product?.price_range?.maximum_price?.final_price.currency
    });
}


useEffect(() => {
    productMeta()
}, []);
```

Please add this const code with other const codes this will work.

Please accept my answer and give upvote if my solution is working.